# When using auth0-spa-js, should I use isAuthenticated() or getTokenSilently() to determine if a user has a valid token?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, single-page-application, auth0, jwt

I am using the [auth0-spa-js](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/auth0-spa-js) SDK with VueJS.

When my application is navigating between pages I want to have [the router navigation guard](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html) check to determine:

- Has a user already been authenticated?
- Is the current JWT the user has still valid?

auth0-spa-js has a couple methods that look like they could be used for this purpose:

- [getTokenSilently](https://auth0.github.io/auth0-spa-js/classes/auth0client.html#gettokensilently)
- [isAuthenticated](https://auth0.github.io/auth0-spa-js/classes/auth0client.html#isauthenticated) (which is really a wrapper around [getUser](https://auth0.github.io/auth0-spa-js/classes/auth0client.html#getuser)).

My question is: Which of these would be better suited to this purpose?

[isAuthenticated](https://auth0.github.io/auth0-spa-js/classes/auth0client.html#isauthenticated) seems simpler, but I'm not sure if it checks whether the user's JWT is expired or not.